# ImportError: cannot import name 'RoboBrowser' from 'robobrowser'

Tags: python-3.7, importerror, robobrowser

I am very new to Python and have used BeautifulSoup to parse and scrape information from some webpages.  Now I need to fill out a form. submit it, and scrape some data after filling in the form, and it seems the easiest way is to use robobrowser.

However, I can't import robobrowser.  I have installed robobrowser several different ways and robobrowser is located here:

```
C:\Users\(USERNAME)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages
```

Here is my script:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import datetime

import webbrowser

import re

from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

br = RoboBrowser()
```

etc....

The problem is the script will not run past "from robobrowser import RoboBrowser" and I get the following message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'RoboBrowser' from 'robobrowser'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your robobrowser package is corrupted

Now try Installing [robobrowser](https://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) using [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)

first check if python package named as [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) is installed on your system using this command in your terminal

```
pip --version
```

if it is installed then it will show the output like that

[image: image showing the message if Pip is installed]

To install [robobrowser](https://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) using PyPI run this command in your terminal

```
pip install robobrowser
```

now import it

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
br = RoboBrowser()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ahwar, I tried to re-install pip but it was installed already, so I upgraded it then re-installed it.  Then I tried to install robobrowser, but it keep saying it's already satisfied.  I ran the script again and kept getting the same error.  Is there another method I can use besides robobrowser?  I was thinking of Scrapy or Selenium, but those seem more advanced for my level.  Thank you again.

Comment: Your import error says that it can't import specific function from the package 'robobrowser' it means that your package is successfully installed but the issue is in importing that specific RoboBrowser() function or class please tell us specifically in detail what you want to do with RoboBrowser

Comment: I want robobrowser to open a webpage, then I want to submit_form to enter information in a search bar, then click the search button to search for what I entered into the form

Comment: Serge! i have no experience in robobrowser
But Open this link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t2f2koZeiiiY-xbEr1aAcq-r1Qk7DF-c 
In this link robobrowser is working you can try whatever you want here
This is [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com)  You need google acocunt to run Python Programs online with it. 
If you don't know how to use this  [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) you can follow this tutorial: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb